# No Audio DELL XPS 13 9333 Haswell Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, dell, alsa

I have been unable to get headphone or internal audio to work on my DELL XPS 13 9333 Haswell with Ubuntu 14.04.

Here is the information I have. I would really appreciate your help.

Alsa Info Script Output: http://pastie.org/pastes/10076091/text

/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf: http://pastie.org/pastes/10076097/text

```
$ lspci -nn | grep -i audio
Controller [8086:0a0c] (rev 0b)
$ uname -a
Linux 3.16.0-33-generic #44~14.04.1-Ubuntu x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
```